# Is there a way to make this variable inside a variable work?

Tags: ansible

I am currently using Ansible to configure collectd, specifically the snmp plugin. In order to create the snmp configuration file I need loop over a variable that's stored within a variable. Although that's what I think I need to do.

I have default host types set so I can automatically know what data which host wants to collect and what MIBS are required for that.

```
types:
  mikrotik_switch:
    collect:
      - "if_speed"
      - "temperature"
      - "processorTemperature"
      - "fanspeed"
    mibs:
      - mib_mikrotik


  tikromik_switch:
    collect:
      - "sif-peed"
      - "rempetature"
      - "tocessorPremperature"
      - "spanfeed"
    mibs:
      - mib_tikromik
```

In the same file (inventory) I set the following variables

```
collectd:
  snmp_port: 161
  config_:  /etc/collectd.conf
  snmp_destinations:
    - { hostname: "best_server_ever",  address: 127.0.0.1, host_type: "{{ types.mikrotik_switch }}", community: "public", version: 2 }
    - { hostname: "smallest_server_ever",  address: 127.0.0.1, host_type: "{{ types.tikromik_switch }}", community: "public", version: 2 }
```

Now I want to create the following output:

```
<Host "best_server_ever">
      Address "127.0.0.1"
      Version 2
      Community "public"
      Collect "if_speed" "temperature" "processorTemperature" "fanspeed"
      Interval 120
         Timeout 10
         Retries 1
</Host>
<Host "smallest_server_ever">
      Address "127.0.0.1"
      Version 2
      Community "public"
      Collect "sif_peed" "rempetature" "tocessorPremperature" "spanfeed"
      Interval 120
         Timeout 10
         Retries 1
</Host>
```

I am stuck and don't know how to loop through the variable stored inside my variable.
My ansible task is currently the following:

```
- name: create collectd config
  blockinfile:
    path: "{{ collectd_config_file }}"
    block: |
      <Host "{{item.hostname | default(item.address)}}" >
        Address "{{item.address}}"
        Version "{{item.version | default(2)}}"
        Community "{{item.community | default("public")}}"
        Collect "{{item.}}"
      </Host>
    insertbefore: "^# INSERT HOSTS"
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK FOR HOST: {{item.hostname}}"
  with_items: "{{ collectd.snmp_hosts }}"
  notify: restart collectd
  tags: collectd
```

Does anyone know what a possible solutions is to my problem?

Comment: You should try the template module in ansible. The Template module is based on jinja2 and supports replacement based condition etc. You can define a vars file in json or list and apply the loop or sub elements logic after sourcing that file using include_vars

Comment: Thanks @error404  I'll try it right away.

Comment: let me know in case you are facing any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a new file, probably the best and fastest way to do it is using a *Jinja2 template* for your file and then ansible *template* module in your playbook.

If you are editing an existing file and you can only use *blockinfile* module, you can access **item.host_type.collect** and use a **join** filter, as shown here:

```
- name: create collectd config
  blockinfile:
    path: "{{ collectd_config_file }}"
    block: |
      <Host "{{item.hostname | default(item.address)}}" >
        Address "{{item.address}}"
        Version "{{item.version | default(2)}}"
        Community "{{item.community | default("public")}}"
        Collect "{{item.host_type.collect | join('" "')}}"
      </Host>
    insertbefore: "^# INSERT HOSTS"
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK FOR HOST: {{item.hostname}}"
  with_items: "{{ collectd.snmp_destinations }}"
  notify: restart collectd
  tags: collectd`
```

Note: Pay attention to with_items loop: the cycle should be on snmp_destinations, not snmp_hosts

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was indeed possible to create a new file. I'm using the template module now.

The blockinfile join filter was useful for another problem I was facing.
This was the answer I needed :)